# How to make a MONO Process() call to launch a process that doesn't die when it parent dies?

Tags: linux, process-management, mono

I'm using Mono on a Linux system to launch a process. Occassionaly the parent process dies an untimely death, and takes the child process with it, but I need to keep the child process going.
In testing, every variation of System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() I've tested will cause it's child process to die when I kill the parent process.
is there some setting I'm missing, or another way to accomplish this?
As a test, this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("journalctl", "-f") {UseShellExecute = true});
```

this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("journalctl", "-f") {UseShellExecute = false});
```

and this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("journalctl", "-f");
```

will launch 'journalctl' ('ps -aef' indicates correct parent-child IDs) and when I kill the parent process, 'journalctl' also dies. 

Should I launch a script that has uses nohup and disown for the the child process?

Answer (score 0):

Complete disassociation of a child process from the parent requires a number of system calls to be made by the child process; these may be easier to do via a shell wrapper if MONO lacks access to the appropriate system calls (`fork` to first create the child process and then `setsid` to escape the parent process group, dealing with the standard input and standard output file handles, possibly a `chdir` to `/`, and anything else I've forgotten). Your MONO calls look more akin to the `system(3)` system call, which also would require using a wrapper program for the `setsid` and such.